# how to change the CSS linear-gradien backgroundt height (thickness)?

Tags: html, css, background

```
background: linear-gradient(left,#000,#000 100%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%,rgba(0,0,0,0));
```

This is the code. I want a 8px line through my text. But this code only gives a 100% height and width for the text background, which covers the text completely.

I hope the final effect would be similar as `text-decoration: line-through`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
background-size: auto 8px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: 0 50%;
```

[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/yst5jdwg/).

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. However, do you know how to add some transition to it? for example, the line would pass from left to right. Now I got some keyframes, and add the code you offered into it, but the final result looks a bit weird: multiple lines appears in but should be only 1... I would post the code and result on fiddle in 3 minutes. By the way, you do not have to answer this question.. since I would of course accept your answer as the best one within 1 hour. And maybe I will need to post another question. (I am not quite familiar with the regulation here)